# jmeter distributed testing on different location

Tags: testing, jmeter, distributed

Jmeter 3.0              jmeter distributed testing -  Can we configure and run scripts on different locations. Different location means not in one building. I want to execute scripts from one location, and connect with other location. Is this possible? Please help.

Comment: any feedback on answer ?, if ok you should accept it and upvote so that users can confidently use it, thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

As you mention "not in one building", it means you may ignore some network concepts like:

- firewall
- ports
- wan
- lan
- ssh

I suggest you start there before.

Comment: Here "not in one building" means different City

Comment: It's the same problem and same concepts enter in the place